How to represent UTM coordinates on the XY plane?
For the sake of clarity: I am very sorry if this question is inaccurate but I find it difficult to understand different terminologies in the geographic information systems.
Let us consider the UTM zone 32U. I am trying to figure out how to represent its north-east and south-east corners on a XY plane. Since these two points are located on the same meridian (12E), I'd expect them to have the same X value on the XY plane (representing only the 32U zone). Now, I am given the lat and lon parameters of these 2 points. If I calculate easting and northing of these two points (wgs84), I get something like:
687071.439112836,  6210141.326581879   (north-east)
723775.9154034771, 5320655.78890633    (south-east)

Although these points are on the same meridian, I cannot use them directly on my XY plane (easting differs due to the characteristic of Mercator projection). I think I could use the UTM declination (convergence angle) calculated for each point and then somehow 'stretch' or 'rotate' them so they have in the end the same X values on my local coordinate system.
Do you have any suggestions how I could achieve that?

32U isn't a UTM zone, 32 is (often delineated 32N or 32S). 32U is a Military Grid Referencing System (MGRS) tile.

@Vince thank you for the explanation, I didn't know that difference. Is it possible to do the projection of the MGRS tile to the XY Euclidean plane? Is my deduction from the original post correct (that we should use the convergence angle for that)?

An MGRS tile is a projected (UTM) map. Longitude doesn't correlate to easting because the UTM cylinder gets wider away from the poles. This sort of Question really needs diagrams if you already know you're not using the same terms the same way.
